# Check async connection to internet with Xam.Plugin.Connectivity

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.forms, async-await

I am trying to verify if my application has access to the internet, for this I occupy the Plugin Xam.Plugin.Connectivity in its version 4 ... The problem is that the answer I receive when Pinging a web is always false

This is the function that I call from the Login of my App ... as you can see it is an async function ...

```
        private async void Login()
        {
            IsRunning = true;
            IsEnabled = false;

            var connection = await apiService.CheckConnection();
            if (!connection.IsSuccess)
            {
                IsRunning = false;
                IsEnabled = true;

                await dialogService.ShowMessage("Error", connection.Message);
                return;
            }

}
```

and this is the class to verify the state of the connection

```
public async Task<Response> CheckConnection()
        {   
            if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
            { 
                    return new Response
                    {
                        IsSuccess = false,
                        Message = "Porfavor active su servicio de internet."
                    };

                }

        var isReachable = await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsRemoteReachable("www.google.com");

                if (!isReachable)
                {

                return new Response
                {
                    IsSuccess = false,
                    Message = "Verifique su conexion a internet."
                };

                }

                else
                {
                    return new Response
                    {
                        IsSuccess = true,
                        Message = "OK"
                    };

                }

            }
```

the problem occurs when it reaches the IsRecheable variable, it takes the false value and does not enter the if it follows ...

[image]

but it returns the state of the "null" connection immediately ...

[image]

and I'm also getting the following error

[image]

I have given the corresponding permissions to run the plugin

what's going on? Any call async that I'm doing wrong? any recommendation with this plugin? some help?

Comment: a correctly formatted uri includes the protocol, "http://www.google.com"

Answer (score 2):

`www.google.com` is not a properly formatted URL as it is missing the protocol (i.e. `http`).

`http://www.google.com` would be a proper formatted URL that can be parsed into all of its URI components.

Example:

```
var isReachable = await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsRemoteReachable("http://www.google.com");
```

Note: `IsRemoteReachable` also can accept just a host name, so `google.com` or `stackoverflow.com` would also work.

Comment: although his answer stops showing the error of the Uri, the problem persists with the same behavior ..... in my section of warning it throws me: 'IConnectivity.IsRemoteReachable(string, int, int)' is obsolete: 'This method is now obsolete and replaced with IsRemoteReachable that take in a full Uri. This method will be removed in future revisions.'.... any help for me? @SushiHangover